# Read a file (with a sparse matrix) and generate CSR

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods

I need to read a square matrix that is in a `.txt` file and store it in the `CSR` format. I know how to read the matrix, but I haven't been able to come with an idea on how to make the `CSR`.

This is the code to read the matrix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
  FILE *f;
  int i,j,n;
  float x;
  f=fopen("file.txt","r");
  if(f=NULL){
  printf(\n No file found \n");
  }
  fscanf(f,"%d",&n);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        fscan(f,"%f",&x);
        printf("\n element (%d,%d) = %f",i,j,x); //this is just to see that the matrix looks like I want it to be, it's not part of CSR problem
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `CSR` is more of an abstract data structure than an actual file format, as far as I know. How exactly do you want the output to be stored?

Comment: `if(f=NULL)` should be `if(f==NULL)` as `=` is the assignment operator but you want `==`, the comparisson operator.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrixfor the CSR format ("stored" in memory).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I'm aware of that article. It doesn't specify a serialisation format, just the abstract structure of two (or three, depending on how you count) arrays. To answer this question, we need to know if OP just wants to build those arrays in memory, or if they want to somehow serialise it.

Comment: @Rhymoid, serialization will be easy if he has built the sparse matrix in memory, which has hasn't yet, so I asume he will be very happy when he has it in memory.

Comment: Hi, what I want is to build those arrays in memory. I don't know what "serialise it" means. Thanks.

Comment: @cathi_w92 To serialise means to turn a data structure into a sequence (or series) of bits. For instance, to write it to a file.

Comment: Hmm, then I think is just build the arrays in memory, because I also need to find, given some (i,j), the value of A(i,j) in the CSR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's interpret the CSR (or CRS, for "compressed row storage") structure as a structure of three arrays:

```
struct csr {
    size_t row_count;
    size_t *row_indices;
    float *values;
    size_t *column_indices;
};
```

Here, `values` and `column_indices` should point to arrays of the same size (alternatively, you could structure them as one array of `int`-`double` pairs), and `row_indices` should point to an array of indices into these two arrays. *(Actually, we're going to take some liberties with `row_indices`; rather than pointing at the first column/value of a row, we're going to point one past the last column/value of the row.)*

Your `*.txt` file format seems to contain a square matrix, and starts with a size parameter (`n`).

```
struct csr your_csr;
size_t n;

fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
your_csr.row_count = n;
```

After reading this `n`, we can allocate `row_indices`. Unfortunately, we don't know how many nonzero values there will be in the matrix. For now, this simple implementation will just allocate `n x n` elements, and a more conservative approach is left as an exercise to the reader.

```
your_csr.row_indices     = calloc(n, sizeof(your_csr.row_indices[0]));
your_csr.values          = calloc(n * n, sizeof(your_csr.values[0]));
your_csr.column_indices  = calloc(n * n, sizeof(your_csr.column_indices[0]));
```

Now that we have our memory in place, let's deal with the matrix data.

```
size_t pair_index = 0;

for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < n; row_index++) {
    for (size_t column_index = 0; column_index < n; column_index++) {
        float value;
        fscanf(f, "%f", &value);
```

For every non-zero value you read, you're going to write what you know into your `values` and `column_indices` array

```
        if (value != 0.0) {
            your_csr.values[pair_index] = value;
            your_csr.column_indices[pair_index] = column_index;
            pair_index++;
        }
    }
```

After you've read a row, you're going to write down where the row ends.

```
    your_csr.row_indices[row_index] = pair_index;
}
```

Now, `your_csr` contains all the data you need to know about the matrix:

- `your_csr.row_count` contains the number of rows in the matrix.
- The length of the other two arrays is `your_csr.row_indices[your_csr.row_count - 1]`.
- If you want to know in which column `your_csr.values[x]` belongs, look at `your_csr.column_indices[x]`.
- The (non-zero) values of the first row (let's call it row 0; mathematicians would disagree, but zero-based indices are great for programming) can be found in `your_csr.values[x]`, where `0 <= x && x < your_csr.row_indices[0]`.
- The values of any other row `r` can be found `your_csr.values[x]`, where `your_csr.values[r - 1] <= x && x < your_csr.row_indices[r]`.